# How to use class patch decorator in unittest.TestCase setUp method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I am currently writing test coverage for a wrapper around sqlite3 in Python. At present my code looks something like this:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from MemberDatabase import MemberDatabase

@patch('sqlite3.connect')
class MemberDatabaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dbConnect(self, mocksql_connect):
        mdb = MemberDatabase('test.db')
        mocksql_connect.assert_called_with('test.db')

    def test_optionalCommit(self, mocksql_connect):
        mdb = MemberDatabase('test.db')
        mdb.optionalCommit()
        self.assertTrue(mocksql_connect().commit.called)
```

Various other tests follow which all create `mdb` in the same way. The constructor of `MemberDatabase` calls `sqlite3.connect()`. I would like to tidy the test case up by moving the assignment of `mdb` to `setUp()`. However, `sqlite3.connect()` isn't mocked in `setUp()` so this results in the actual `sqlite3.connect()` being called and a real database connection being created.

Is there any way to use the patched `sqlite3.connect()` in `setUp()`? Perhaps I need to create the mock inside `setUp()` instead of using the decorator, but I think the code is cleaner using the decorator approach. Also, I read that if I create mock

Comment: I'd recommend just putting the patch into `setUp` (using `addCleanup` to stop the patch after the tests run).  I've never liked using any of the various `patch` methods as class decorators -- Mostly because it separates the argument list from the code which guarantees that those parameters will be passed and introduces ambiguity (what if you decorate the class with one patch and a specific method with another -- What's the order of the parameters then?)

Comment: You should mock the `MemberDatabase.sqlite3.connect` instead `sqlite3.connect`.

Comment: @mgilson I went with your approach in the end. The code is cleaner now.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I've been told before that `sqlite3` and `MemberDatabase.sqlite3` are the same as `import sqlite3` in MemberDatabse just brings in a reference to `sqlite3`. As such I was previously advised to just mock `sqlite3`. Your way is certainly more explicit (a good thing!). Are there any other differences between the two?